# Media Player setDataSource

Tags: android

A função `setDataSource()` funciona com um *url*, mas preciso que vá buscar um ficheiro no meu *raw* (por exemplo).

Usei:

```
Uri url = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + ctx.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.file);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url.toString());
```

Mas não funciona.

Answer (score 2):

O método `setDataSource()` tem vários *overloads*, aquele que você está a tentar utilizar recebe um *path*.
O método `toString()` da classe *Uri* não retorna um *path* mas sim a representação, em *string*, da *uri* com que foi construída.

Aquilo que você está a fazer é o equivalente a isto:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("android.resource://" + ctx.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.file);
```

No fundo não está a utilizar a *Uri* que construiu na linha:

```
Uri url = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + ctx.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.file);
```

Deve portanto utilizar o *overload* do método `setDataSource()` que recebe um *uri*:

```
Uri url = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + ctx.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.file);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(ctx, url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Funciona se for um ficheiro local, mas é um ficheiro de streaming (um url)

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = ctx.getAssets().openFd("file.txt");
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
```

em que o file.txt tem o url por exemplo, não funciona.

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que quer dizer. Não consigo perceber a sua resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Eu tenho um ficheiro - `file.m3u8` com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
EXTM3U  
    EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="bipbop_audio",LANGUAGE="eng",NAME="BipBop Audio 1",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=YES
    EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="bipbop_audio",LANGUAGE="eng",NAME="BipBop Audio 2",AUTOSELECT=NO,DEFAULT=NO,URI="alternate_audio_aac_sinewave/prog_index.m3u8"
```

Esse ficheiro reproduz um vídeo se tiver num servidor.

Eu pretendo ter esse ficheiro dentro do meu apk e reproduzir o ficheiro usando o Media Player com `setDataSource("file.m3u8")`